# Take string from an input, and pick out part of that text to print its definition from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, input

I'm relatively new to python, I have made a few pieces of very simple code, and I'm struggling to implement a program that prompts the user for the name of a file (e.g. : cat.png) and then outputs that file’s media type (e.g. : .png). If the file’s name ends, case-insensitively, in any of these suffixes:

```
-.gif
-.jpg
-.jpeg
-.png
-.pdf
-.txt
-.zip
```

Then I want to print out its corresponding meaning:

```
-image/gif
-image/jpeg
-image/jpeg
-image/png
-application/text
-text/plain
-application/zip
```

e.g. :

```
My desired output:
$ python extensions.py
File name: cat.gif
image/gif
$ python extensions.py
File name: cat.jpg
image/jpg
```

I've tried to solve this problem using a dictionary, to match a name to its corresponding format:

```
file_name = input('File name: ').strip().lower()
extensions = [
    {'name': '.gif', 'format': 'image/gif' },
    {'name': '.jpg', 'format': 'image/jpeg' },
    {'name': '.jpeg', 'format' :'image/jpeg' },
    {'name': '.png', 'format': 'image/png' },
    {'name': '.pdf', 'format': 'application/text' },
    {'name': '.txt', 'format': 'text/plain' },
    {'name': '.zip', 'format': 'application/zip' }
    ]
```

Problem is, I don't know how to turn a user output like `cat.png` into a file like `.png` and printed on the terminal as `image/png` like the picture above. I'm trying to find a way to somehow somehow take the `.png` part out of the 'cat.png', and pass it through a dictionary, printing out the `image/png`.

Appreciate you reading this long description. Anyone have ideas to implement such a program maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should not be much of an issue.

- First, create a dictionary of {extension:explanation} items.
- Then, ask the user to enter the filename.
- Then, split the file name by dot, take the part after dot. You can use the `partition` method for that.
- Finally, query your dictionary and return the output.

Code:

```py
# First, create a dictionary of {extension:explanation} items.
extensions_dict {
    'png': 'image/media'
    # put as much as you wish
}

# Then, ask the user to enter the filename.
user_file = input('file name: ')

# Then, split the file name by dot, take the part after dot.
file_name, dot, file_extension = user_file.partition('.')

# Finally, query your dictionary and return the output.
# You can print a message to the user as a default 
# if the extension is not in your dictionary
print(extensions_dict.get(
  file_extension,
  f'I cannot understand your extension ({file_extension}) :('
)
```

Comment: Your code was full of bugs. I fixed them for you (and other readers). Next time test your answer code before you post it.

Comment: Thanks, much @buhtz. I edited the code. It should be fine now. I also used better var names.

Comment: Appreciate all the help @MagedSaeed

Answer (score 2):

```
import os

file_name = 'cat.png'
extensions = {
    '.gif': 'image/gif',
    '.jpg': 'image/jpeg' ,
    '.jpeg': 'image/jpeg' ,
    '.png': 'image/png' ,
    '.pdf': 'application/text' ,
    '.txt': 'text/plain' ,
    '.zip': 'application/zip'
    }

print(extensions[os.path.splitext(file_name)[1]])
```

So first of all, I have changed the structure of the `extensions` - there is no real need to be so repetitive and keep a list of dicts which would be much harder to browse through. Using extensions as keys, you can refer to them directly to find respective format.

Then you can use `splitext` method from Python `os.path` module to get a string representing file extensions (which works better for various edge cases than `str.split`)

Answer (score 0):

If the file name is really just the file name with one dot in it, then you can use `.split()` to get the extension:

```
file_extension = file_name.split('.')[-1]
```

By way of explanation: `split.('.')` splits up the string that you've entered with the dot as the separator and returns a list, and the [-1] index gives you the last item in that list, i.e., the extension.

You can then look up that extension in your dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions are fine and OK. But I want to offer you a more pythonic way using Pythons `pathlib` package to handle file path objects the platform independent way and some other tweaks.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import pathlib  # recommended way with Python3

media_types_dict = {
    'png': 'image/media',
    'gif': 'image/gif',
    # ...
}

# ask the user
user_file = input('file name: ')

# convert to a file path object
user_file = pathlib.Path(user_file)

# get the extension (with the trailing dot, e.g. ".png")
extension = user_file.suffix

# remove the dot
extension = extension[1:]

try:
    # get the media type
    media_type = media_types_dict[extension.lower()]
except KeyError:  # if the extensions is not present in the dict
    raise Exception(f'The extension "{extension}" is unknown.')

# output the result
print(media_type)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `split(".")` may create error if user inputs without a dot(.) It may not be more pythonic but using if....elif....else would solve this problem.

```
x=input("enter filename with extension: ").lower()
if x.endswith(".gif"):
    print("image/gif")
elif x.endswith(".jpg"):
    print("image/jpg")
elif x.endswith(".jpeg"):
    print("image/jpeg")
elif x.endswith(".png"):
    print("image/png")
elif x.endswith(".pdf"):
    print("document/pdf")
elif x.endswith(".txt"):
    print("text/txt")
elif x.endswith(".zip"):
    print("archive/zip")
else:
    print("application/octet-stream")
```